# Find $b$ such that we know the solution $x$ of $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So, $A$ is a $n$ x $n$ matrix where:

- All the diagonal elements are $1$
- All the elements on the lower triangular part are $-1$
- The elements on the $n^{th}$ column are $1$
- And every other element is $zero$

I am trying to find $b$ such that we already know what $x$ is without caring about the value of $n$.

I tried to use a $b$ similar to the one we use in $H_n x=b$ where $H_n$ is a $n$ x $n$ Hilbert matrix but still I couldn't specifically define the $x$.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by elements of $n^{th}$

Comment: the elements on the $n_{th}$ column, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try $b$ = first column of $A$; then $x = e_1$. Alternatively, pick $b$ = last column of $A$ and then $x = e_n$. Indeed, this works for any column. :)

Comment: I am sorry but what $e_n$ is?

Comment: $e_k$ is a vector of all zeroes except the $k$th entry, which is a $1$. In $\Bbb R^3$, for instance, $e_2$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and  $e_3$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. For any dimension $k$, the vector $e_k$ is all zeroes except the last element, which is $1$.

Comment: Oh, that seems right. Thank you!